# Understanding a code snippet in verilog

Tags: aes, verilog

I found the following code snippet in verilog code for AES.

```
function [7:0] xtime;
input [7:0] b; xtime={b[6:0],1'b0}^(8'h1b&{8{b[7]}});
endfunction
```

Please explain what does this do. The more elaborate explanation, the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b is a 8 bit input.

b[6:0],1'b0 last 7 bits left shifted, and padded with 0

^ xor

8'h1b   8 bits hex 1b anded with the sign bit.

Explained in one line: If msb is set xor with 0x1b otherwise just *2

A quick search of xtime and AES leads me to this c implementation’s comment:

```
// xtime is a macro that finds the product of {02} and the argument to
// xtime modulo {1b}  
#define xtime(x)   ((x<<1) ^ (((x>>7) & 1) * 0x11b))
```

looks like it maybe is doing about the same.

Comment: Does, 8{b[7]} mean the MSB?

Comment: `b[7]` means bit 7, which in this case is the MSB. `{8{1'b1}}` means repeat `1'b1` 8 times.

Comment: b[7] is the left most bit, but it is expanded as every bit - In the c macro this is the multiplication with 1 or 0. In an asic implementation this is implemented as a expended bit ANDed the constant

Comment: Also here `8'h1b` means `00011011` in binary. Right?

Comment: I was just going to accept your answer when Morgan answered.

Comment: parameter as in input but I changed it

Answer (score 1):

Lets clean up the code and breakdown some of the assignments:

```
function [7:0] xtime;
  input [7:0] b; 
  reg   [7:0] temp1;
  reg   [7:0] temp2;
  begin
    temp1  = {b[6:0],1'b0};
    temp2  = ( 8'h1b & {8{b[7]}} ); 
    xtime  = temp1 ^ temp2;
  end
endfunction
```

Function called `xtime` outputs the variable `xtime` 8 bits wide. Has 8 bit wide input called b.

`temp1` left shifts input b, padding LSB (Least Significant Bit) with 0 and throwing away MSB (Most Significant Bit).

`temp2` bitwise `AND`s `8'h1B` (8'b0001_1011) with the MSB of input b.

`b[7]` selects bit 7 of `b`.
`{8{value}}` is the replication operator.

```
{8{1'b1}}  => 8'b1111_1111
{4{2'b10}} => 8'b1010_1010
```

`xtime` performs the bitwise `XOR` of `temp1` and `temp2`.